# CSS not working when added to site.css file in ASP.NET Core project. But works when added as inline

Tags: css, animation, svg, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm testing an `svg animation` example (taken from **Live Example** section from [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)) on an `ASP.NET Core` project.

Image displays ok. When I add the following `css` **inline** to a specific `view`, the **animation** works but animation does NOT work when I add the same `css` to the site.css file (located by default at `myProject\wwwroot\cs\site.css`). Why?

**View** [Animation works after I moved the related css inside the view]

```
<div>
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
             width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">

        <path class="path" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M66.039,133.545c0,0-21-57,18-67s49-4,65,8
            s30,41,53,27s66,4,58,32s-5,44,18,57s22,46,0,45s-54-40-68-16s-40,88-83,48s11-61-11-80s-79-7-70-41
            C46.039,146.545,53.039,128.545,66.039,133.545z" />  
    </svg>
</div>
@section css{
    <style>
        .path {
            stroke-dasharray: 1000;
            stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
            animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
        }

        @@keyframes dash {
            from {
                stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
            }

            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
}
```

**Snapshot of myProject\wwwroot\css\site.css file**: [Animation did NOT work when the the above css was added to the end of following site.css file.

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
...
...
}

/*I added for svg animation test*/
.path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    }

    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the UseStatic middleware is not serving `.cs` files as static `css`. Use the proper css extension.

Answer (score 20):

Had a similar problem and the solution was to force load the css (crtl+F5 in the browser). My browser had chached the old version and IIS Express does not force load it from source.

Comment: How could we force it to load it from the source ?

Comment: @ChristopheChenel  Open chrome dev tools, hold the left key mouse on reload page button [and you see these options](https://prnt.sc/1zpfh8y) -> press "Empty Cache and Hard Reload", so it refreshes cached styles.

Answer (score 9):

Add `app.UseStaticFiles();` in startup.cs --> Configure methode

if you did it and dosent work again add version to your css link like bellow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=enter here version number" />
```

for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=101" />
```

update version number when change your css file

> you can use it for js files.
>
> if you do this, user dose not need to press ctrl+f5

Answer (score 6):

Check the link in your _Layout.cshtml file.  It sets the default to the site.min.css version of the CSS, not the site.css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

change it to your decompressed full css file, site.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

My Identity _Layout.cshtml (/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml) was referencing the site.css from Identity (~/Identity/css/site.css), that apparently does not gets scaffolded.

My solution was to reference the site.css that is located in the project (wwwroot/css/site.css) in the _Laout.cshtml file.

old:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Identity/css/site.css" />
```

new:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Not having asp-append-version = "true" in _layout.cshtml also could be a reason behind not rendering site.css. Try adding that if you forget that.

--Without asp-append-version="true"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css"/>
```

--With asp-append-version="true"

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be anythin Nam, but check for the following
1) the file name should be site.css(CSS file) and not site.cs(C# file). You are indeed working with a CSS file aren't you?
2) If you have your file named appropriately you should check that the browser isn't loading a cached version of your CSS file.

Comment: That was just a typo in the post (thank you for pointing that out). I've corrected the typo it should be `site.css`. But the issue persists event after I cleared the cache from the browser and clicked on `Clean Solution`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, i tried ~/css/main but didnt work and I wrote

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../wwwroot/css/main.css"/>
```

and it workes for me.